# Check if button is pressed with id

Tags: javascript

```
 <div class="osciladores">
        <button class="oscilador" id="sine">Sinusoidal</button>
        <button class="oscilador" id="triangle">Triangle</button>
        <button class="oscilador" id="square">Square</button>
        <button class="oscilador" id="sawtooth">Sawtooth</button>
      </div>

 if(document.getElementById('square').clicked == true){
  console.log("hi!");
  //something
  }
```

I'm trying to do something when my "square" button is clicked searching for its own id, but it doesn't work, any suggestions?

Comment: Suggest you study some tutorials on user events

Comment: A down vote has nothing to do with you personally. It is related to the long term value of a question (or answer) as part of the repository of knowledge that the site represents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.clicked` isn't a thing. Any event that happens must used with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or [`onevent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers).

```
document.getElementById('square').onclick = function(event) {
  // What to do after button is clicked
}
```

Or with `addEventListener`

```
function clicked(event) {
  // What to do after button is clicked
}
document.getElementById('square').addEventListener(clicked);
```

Note that in `addEventListener` there are no parentheses to call the `clicked` function.

[List of possible events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

Comment: But is there no way to check if it is true or false that the button has been clicked?

Comment: @pighfs You don't have to check if the button is "true" or "false". If it gets clicked, it gets clicked. There is no true or false in any event in Javascript.

Comment: Sure it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Use onclick:

```
 document.getElementById('square').onclick =  function() { 
    console.log("Hey1 I did it")
  }
```

**Support**

Dear developer, you can use `onclick` to determine whether the button with `ID = "Square"` is clicked or not, if it is been clicked then, a function will be passed, that log the answer to your console.